# Function that checks if current frame is not an X window

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is it possible to check from within an elisp function if the current emacs frame is an X window or a terminal?

I have a function that maximizes the window, and it's set to run whenever a new frame is created. However, when I open a terminal-only session I get error messages whenever a new frame is created.

I want the function to check whether it is an X window, and do nothing otherwise. Is that possible?

*For the record, here is the current function:*

```
(defun fullscreen (&optional f)     
  (interactive)                      ;if called interactively, use current frame
  (if f (select-frame f))            ;if called as hook, use new frame
  (x-send-client-message nil 0 nil "_NET_WM_STATE" 32
                    '(2 "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT" 0))
  (x-send-client-message nil 0 nil "_NET_WM_STATE" 32
                    '(2 "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ" 0))
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may look at the `window-system` function. It accepts a frame optional argument (defaults to current frame). Alternatively, `display-graphic-p` is more recent (as per the documentation) and allows checking a whole display containing several frames. In your example, you could just write:

```
(if (display-graphic-p) ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `framep' since its return value is defined (according to`C-h f framep`) as:

```
Return non-nil if OBJECT is a frame.
Value is:
  t for a termcap frame (a character-only terminal),
 'x' for an Emacs frame that is really an X window,
 'w32' for an Emacs frame that is a window on MS-Windows display,
 'ns' for an Emacs frame on a GNUstep or Macintosh Cocoa display,
 'pc' for a direct-write MS-DOS frame.
See also `frame-live-p'.
```